# Corrutinas en Kotlin, ¿cómo hacer que el hilo espere el resultado del get() lanzado a FIREBASE?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, corrutinas

he creado una corrutina dentro de una función para conseguir, mediante el withContext, que el hilo esperase el resultado del get() lanzado a firestore. Sin embargo, parece que el método get() crea un hilo aparte, así que no consigo que la corrutina espere a que se asignen a las variables sus correspondientes valores. La ejecución continúa, y las variables se quedan con sus valores por defecto, no con los valores recogidos en  firestore.

¿Cómo debo usar la corrutina para que espere el resultado solicitado al firestore mediante el método get()? ¿Hay una forma alternativa para hacer lo que quiero?

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {

      val recyclerView: RecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler1)
      recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

      val database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

      withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
         database.collection("grupos").document("2").get().addOnSuccessListener {
           nombreEvent = it.getString("name")
           artista = it.getString("artista")
           descripcion = it.getString("descripcion")
           lugar = it.getString("lugar")
           imagen = it.getString("imagen")
         }
       }

       val adapterRec = RecyclerAdapter( listOf(Grupo("id", nombreEvent, artista, descripcion, lugar,imagen)))
       recyclerView.adapter = adapterRec
            
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya he encontrado la solución al problema que planteaba con esta corrutina; primero, tenía que usar la función await() para que el hilo principal esperase la respuesta de la consulta lanzada.
Además de eso, tenía que incluir todo dentro de un try..catch para capturar la excepción en el caso de que no se encontrasen datos en la consulta realizada.

```
try{
      val database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

      withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
         database.collection("grupos").document("2").get().addOnSuccessListener {
           nombreEvent = it.getString("name")
           artista = it.getString("artista")
           descripcion = it.getString("descripcion")
           lugar = it.getString("lugar")
           imagen = it.getString("imagen")
         }
       }.await()
} catch (e: Exception) {
            println("exception: ${e.message}")
}

       val adapterRec = RecyclerAdapter( listOf(Grupo("id", nombreEvent, artista, descripcion, lugar,imagen)))
       recyclerView.adapter = adapterRec
```